# How to declare Callable to execute function returning void in Java?

Tags: java, concurrency, future, callable

Suppose I would like to run static method `foo` asynchronously

```
void foo() throws Exception {...}
```

Since `foo` throws an exception I would prefer create a `Callable` and invoke `ExecutorService.submit` with it to get a `Future`.

Now I wonder how to declare those `Callable` and `Future` properly. 
Should I declare them

```
Callable<Void> and Future<Void>?
```

Comment: Yes.Callable<Void>. But void is not compatible with Void, so you have to call your foo() from a wrapper method returning Void.

Comment: Why not Callble<T> and Future<T>?

Comment: @TomF why not Callable<? extend T> and Future<? extends T>?

Comment: I don't know, that is why i asked why

Comment: I missed the capital V.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> Should I declare them `Callable<Void>` and `Future<Void>`?

Yes.

`Void` is similar to the wrapper classes `Integer`, `Long` etc. for the primitive types `int`, `long` etc. You could say it's a wrapper class for `void`, even though `void` is not really a type.

Comment: And as you have to return a result of type Void, your Callback#call() method has to return null.

And thus, as you anyway have to return, you might use Boolean as return type and return Boolean.TRUE (or in case of an error Boolean.FALSE). So it just might have better readability.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should declare them `Callable<?>` and `Future<?>`.  Then you can implement them anyway you want including `Callable<Void>` and `Future<Void>`.

Comment: Nope, it won't work in the situation OP asked about.